# duplicate result in left join query

Tags: c#, sql

```
select
  Users.emp as 'No',
  Users.username as Name,
  SUM(Inv_SubEMP.exchange_price) as Erad,
  coalesce(SandSD.val, 0) as s7obat, 
  ISNULL(Isnull(SUM(Inv_SubEMP.exchange_price),0) -
         IsNull(SandSD.val, 0),0) as Totol  
from
(
  (
    (Users join Inv_SubEMP on Users.username = Inv_SubEMP.emp
            and userType = 1 and IS_Deleted = 0)
    left join InvEMP on InvEMP.proc_id = Inv_SubEMP.proc_id
  )
  left join SandSD on SandSD.emp_id = Users.emp 
        and SandSD.IS_Deleted = 0
)
where InvEMP.IS_Deleted = 0
group by Users.emp, Users.username, Inv_SubEMP.emp, SandSD.val 
order by Users.emp
```

[image]

This query is gathered different functions then is put together with another function, but I basically want to know how I could re-write the LEFT JOIN section to work properly.

I'm trying to add on my own left join here so that .. the result some time work correctly and some time not .. sometimes i fined delicate like no. 10 in pic
Thanks alot

Comment: They have different `s7obat` values, and you are grouping by that. What would you like it to do different?

Comment: If you only grouped by `Users.username` you would get a single row per username. But... you are grouping by multiple columns.

Comment: i can't just  grouping it just by user.userName ** Column 'Users.emp' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Which s7obat value is correct for the shop username: 30 or 50?

Comment: please provide sample data

Comment: What does this have to do with C#? Please remove the `C#` tag.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Both of them is Correct .. the result must Sum 30+50 and get 80

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select
  Users.emp as 'No',
  Users.username as Name,
  SUM(Inv_SubEMP.exchange_price) as Erad,
  SUM(coalesce(SandSD.val, 0)) as s7obat, 
  ISNULL(Isnull(SUM(Inv_SubEMP.exchange_price),0) -
         IsNull(SandSD.val, 0),0) as Totol  
from
(
  (
    (Users join Inv_SubEMP on Users.username = Inv_SubEMP.emp
            and userType = 1 and IS_Deleted = 0)
    left join InvEMP on InvEMP.proc_id = Inv_SubEMP.proc_id
  )
  left join SandSD on SandSD.emp_id = Users.emp 
        and SandSD.IS_Deleted = 0
)
where InvEMP.IS_Deleted = 0
group by Users.emp, Users.username, Inv_SubEMP.emp
order by Users.emp
```